# In Doctor Who "The Tsuranga Conundrum" what are they looking for in the junkyard?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who "The Tsuranga Conundrum" what are they looking for on the junkyard planet? Did I miss where they said what they were looking for? It seemed important as all of them were looking for it.

Comment: According to [this transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=doctor-who&episode=s11e05), they didn't say what they were looking for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thanks for that, hopefully it gets explained next episode...

Comment: @Pikachun “hopefully it gets explained next episode” — I wouldn’t pin your hopes on that.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Yeah, I know... but you never know considering that the Dr still needs to get the Tardis back and it is afterall parked on the junkyard planet.

Comment: @Pikachun - At the end of the episode they were planning to teleport her and the gang back to the planet. I think we can assume they got back safely and found the TARDIS unmolested

Comment: @Valorum - oh well... it would seem that the whole point of being on the Junkyard planet will never be revealed... so it was just a Segway into them getting hurt to be on a hospital ship.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @RemyLebeau for the [Episode transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=doctor-who&episode=s11e05) we can see that the item is never named however it is actually shown on screen :-

Approximately 1 minute into the episode (based on BBC iPlayer timings) the Doctor says the line "Maybe 59's the one with a big pile of these."

She is holding a cylindrical object (see image)

[image]

Comment: Ah, of course. It's one of *those*.

Comment: Huh. I assumed that wasn't actually what they were looking for, rather just something that was on the planet they were supposed to be on, since a) Ryan says "We're never gonna find one" and b) The Doctor said she found 7 last time she was here, which I wouldn't call "a big pile".

Comment: @ElibE876  fair point. a) I assumed that they had brought that one with them from the TARDIS and were hunting for one to replace it,  -  After all they are on a junk planet where else would you dump your broken gear. and b) I just took that as Hyperbole.

I do agree though that your interpretation could also be correct

Comment: @EdHunter - I thought the same way as ElibE867's comment, I though she was just holding that because it was something nearby she though was interesting... as later when she is sonic'ing the mine she is no longer holding that item.